# R: Simulating ERGM model in R then generate adjacency matrix of that model

Tags: r, networking, graph, igraph

I use `library(ergm)` and `library(igraph)` and generate a ERGM network. But I want the adjacency matrix of that network. I am unable to find any function which can produce that.

```
library(ergm)
library(igraph)
g.use <- network(16,density=0.1,directed=FALSE)
#
# Starting from this network let's draw 3 realizations
# of a edges and 2-star network
#
g.sim <- simulate(~edges+kstar(2), nsim=3, coef=c(-1.8,0.03),
              basis=g.use, control=control.simulate(
                MCMC.burnin=1000,
                MCMC.interval=100))
#g.sim[[3]]
summary(g.sim)
```

Is it possible to find the adjacency matrix from `g.sim`? and how?

Comment: why are you using/loading `igraph` library? The `ergm` package uses the `network` library and not the `igraph`. Do not mix the two. Note that your code should run without the `library(igraph)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EGRM package uses the `network` package and not the `igraph` package. You should maintain everythig in `network` and not load `igraph` as the two have some conflicting functions with same names.

In your case, you simulate 3 graphs thus you should have 3 adjacency matrices. The code is as below:

```
library(ergm)
g.use <- network(16,density=0.1,directed=FALSE)
g.sim <- simulate(~edges+kstar(2), nsim=3, coef=c(-1.8,0.03),
              basis=g.use, control=control.simulate(
                MCMC.burnin=1000,
                MCMC.interval=100))
```

The code you want:

```
lapply(g.sim, as.matrix)

[[1]]
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
3  0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1
4  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
6  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
7  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1
8  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0
9  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
10 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
11 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
13 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1
14 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
16 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0

[[2]]
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
2  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
3  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
4  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
6  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1
7  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
8  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
9  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
11 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
12 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
13 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
15 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
16 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0

[[3]]
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1
2  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
3  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0
4  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
5  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6  0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
7  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0
8  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
11 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
12 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0
13 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
14 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
15 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1
16 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0
```